# Generating a data table from a CGI query with wget?

Tags: database, cgi, wget

I need to create a dataset (a CSV table) based on multiple CGI queries in a statistical database of scientific citations and publications. Right now I'm filtering the initial data manually, doing CGI queries "by hand" and then copy-pasting the results to Excel. But is it possible to fetch the whole initial dataset using WGET instead?

In other words, can a CGI database be exported as CSV or any other flatfile?

I tried to follow [this example](http://forum.netfort.com/netfort/topics/using_wget_to_run_reports). But what I got was a file with just some HTML output. Here's what a typical query looked like:

```
wget -S -o webofscience_log.txt -O webofscience_data.txt "http://esi.webofknowledge.com/rankdatapage.cgi?option=C&search=ESTONIA&searchby=N"
```

I do realize that I didn't include any indicators for a CSV output. How should I do this?

Or -- if this kind of query isn't possible, what are my alternatives for fetching the data (considering that it's initially a CGI query)?

Thanks for any advice!